# Terminal vs PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shell

I am been currently studying AWS, and my online instructor uses "Windows PowerShell", however, I have always used "Hyper Terminal" for MERN stack. What is the difference between the two, and what sets this two apart from the Command Prompt?

Comment: Understand the difference between an operating-system shell/scripting-language  and a tool to connect to other computers by emulating a computer-terminal.

Comment: How is MERN related to any terminal? I also think that this is not a good question what kind of answer to you expect? Why dont you ask your instructor?

Comment: I've heard of MERN, but what is "Hyper Terminal"?

Comment: Thank Mao for your input!

Comment: @The Fool, MERN is related to the terminal because you preform a lot of Node.js & MongoDB functions from your computers terminal, as you used such commands like `Nodeman app.js` to run your file, as well as `db.db_name.find()`. Moreover, I can not directly message my instructor, to answer your question.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Hyper Terminal is the name of the program I use, that, from the best of my limited knowledge preforms the same functions as a Command Prompt but with added abilities. or, that is as far as I know it to be.

Comment: mern is as much related to the terminal as any other programing stuff really. Plus keep in mind that when you run your node commands you not actually using the build in terminal functionality so it doest matter at all. If you were interested in scripting in powershell vs some other shell, that would be a different story but invoking some cli commands can be done with anything.

Comment: @TheFool Good point, I was wondering why terminals could run the same command as a shell, as far as I know. I am a newbie, only about 8 months in, it's alot. haha

Comment: In case of code examples, sometimes there are different line wraps "\" vs "\`" or env-variable-usage `$pwd` and `${pwd}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Hyper Terminal but I see there are terminal emulators online that go by that name therefore I assume you may be using a third party terminal emulator.

PowerShell is a newer shell and also happens to be an object-oriented scripting language.

As far as Windows shells go, I can use PowerShell to do anything I used to do with CMD. Generally speaking, I would say PowerShell really shines when it comes to Windows System administration which is my primary use for it and it saves me a great deal of time.

As far as terminal emulators go, I feel the default terminals for both PowerShell and CMD are pretty much the same and are very lacking compared to 3rd party offerings or even the default terminal that comes in any modern Linux OS.

For a free "Microsoft" alternative to replace your default terminal, I would recommend the open-source "Windows Terminal" app. The addition of tabs, panes, zoom function, easy to read text, and easy ways to start different shells (such and CMD or PowerShell) or even start a WSL session with your choice of Linux OS is a major improvement to the default Windows terminal app.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the simple answer:

PowerShell Preview replaced PowerShell, and PowerShell replaced Command Prompt (CMD).

Windows Terminal is an application that simply provides tabs to open multiple instances of PowerShell (Preview or legacy) and Command Prompt, as well as Azure cloud shell.

In Linux. you'll often hear the terms 'terminal' and 'console' used interchangeably, but they mean the same in Linux as they do in Windows.  That is, console is the Linux alternative to the DOS style command prompt.

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation. Powershell is very powerful if you know how to use it (and yes, it's multi-platform (sort of) now).  I run huge transactions each day for my corporation using a 350 line script, and it works, and has worked for years. It's similar to python but IMHO way better as you don't have to go get all the modules.  :)